# Find the value of $\sqrt{1+2\sqrt{1+3\sqrt{1+....}}}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, limits, radicals, nested-radicals

**Find the value of**
 $$\sqrt{1+2\sqrt{1+3\sqrt{1+....}}}$$

> I have done a similar question before in which only a single number is involved, for example    $\sqrt{2+2\sqrt{2+2\sqrt{2+....}}}$ which can easily be solved due to repetition of the expression. For this question, when I set the whole thing equal to $f(x)$, I got this
>   $$[f(x)]^2=xf(x+1)+1$$
>   After that, I'm not able to solve this functional equation further. Is there any particular method for solving these types of functional equations?
>   Any help will be appreciated.
>   Thanks!